# Sequelize sort records in LIFO before querying

Tags: sequelize.js

I performed a pagination of a mysql table using ORM sequelize.
everything works correctly for me, but I would like to have the last one inserted as the first record displayed.

I tried with the REVERSE() function which works fine. except that it only reverses the records extracted from the query.

I would like a reversal of the entire database and then the records are returned to me in the correct order. starting from the last one inserted.

is it possible to achieve this with sequelize???

```
`Flights.findAll({    
    where: { Id_user: ID_User },
    order: ["timestart" ],
    limit: limit, 
    offset: offset,
    include: [
        {
            model: user,
            as: "person",
         },
     ]
})
.then((data) => {
    data.reverse();
    console.log("JSON DATA:", JSON.stringify(data, null, 2));
    const response = getPagingData(`your text`data, ntotalevoli, offset, limit);
    res.send(response);
})`
```

Reverse the query you made.
I would like it to be on the entire database so the reverse should be before the query

Comment: reversing the order as in `order: ["timestart", "desc"]`?

Comment: I had already tried to put order DESC.

only I get the following error:
message
:
"Unknown column 'flights.desc' in 'order clause'"

Comment: maybe `order: [["timestart", "desc"]]`? the [docs](https://sequelize.org/docs/v6/core-concepts/model-querying-basics/) says you can add `desc` keyword to the query did give example to specify the column and modifier in an array. sorry, i haven't wrote anything in sequelize for years.

Comment: many thanks for your help,
now it works correctly